How to Print a Route in Thingsboard
I´m new with Thinsboard. At the moment, I have created a dashboard where I display 2 locations (hubs) and a vehicle. However, I´m trying to display a route but I´m not sure how.
My current approach is the following:
I create a route based on a JSON, as follows:
 "route":{
            "name": "Route for Working Plan 1",
            "num_route": 0,
            "pos":  0,
            "arrival_time": "",
            "departure_time": "",
            "arr_veh_weight": 0.0,
            "dep_veh_weight": 0.0,
            "arrive_veh_items": 0,
            "dep_veh_items": 0,
            "accu_distance_km": 0.0,
            "point_List":
              "(41.6721, -0.8899), (41.6705, -0.8902), (41.6688, -0.8904), (41.6672, -0.8907), (41.6656, -0.8909), (41.6639, -0.8912), (41.6623, -0.8914), (41.6607, -0.8917), (41.6590, -0.8919), (41.6574, -0.8922), (41.6558, -0.8924), (41.6542, -0.8927), (41.6525, -0.8929), (41.6509, -0.8932), (41.6493, -0.8934), (41.6476, -0.8937), (41.6460, -0.8939), (41.6444, -0.8942), (41.6427, -0.8944), (41.6411, -0.8947)"
        }

Then, I send the telemetry like this, using timestamp:
 telemetry = []

        ts = int(time.time() * 1000)
        for route_point in route_points_lat:
            ts = ts

            telemetry.append({
                "ts": ts,
                "values": {
                    "latitude": route_point,
                    "longitude": route_points_lon[pos]
                }
            })

            pos += 1
            ts += 1000
 
            ...
        try:
            route_point_tb_asset = API.find_asset(route.name)
            send_telemetry_asset(token, route_point_tb_asset.id.id, telemetry)
            print(f"Telemetry properly sent to {route.name}")


After this, all I see is the last point sent to the asset.
How can I achieve a route display? What I want is something like this:


The issue you're experiencing, where only the last point of telemetry is sent to the asset, likely stems from how you're managing the ts (timestamp) and the pos variable within your loop. Here’s a breakdown of potential problems and solutions:
Potential Issues

Reusing ts without Incrementing:

In your loop, you have ts = ts, which effectively does nothing. You need to ensure that the timestamp is correctly incremented for each telemetry entry.


Indexing with pos:

You are using pos to index into route_points_lon, but you need to ensure that pos is initialized correctly and does not exceed the length of your longitude list.


Telemetry List Initialization:

Ensure that telemetry is initialized as an empty list before the loop starts.


Sending Telemetry:

Make sure that you are sending the telemetry data after you've populated it completely, not just after one iteration.



Revised Code Example
Here’s a corrected version of your code snippet:
import time

# Assuming route_points_lat and route_points_lon are defined and have the same length
route_points_lat = [41.6721, 41.6705, 41.6688, 41.6672, 41.6656]  # Example latitudes
route_points_lon = [-0.8899, -0.8902, -0.8904, -0.8907, -0.8909]  # Example longitudes

telemetry = []

# Initialize timestamp
ts = int(time.time() * 1000)

# Ensure pos starts at 0
pos = 0

# Loop through latitude points
for route_point in route_points_lat:
    telemetry.append({
        "ts": ts,
        "values": {
            "latitude": route_point,
            "longitude": route_points_lon[pos]
        }
    })

    # Increment pos for longitude indexing
    pos += 1
    
    # Increment timestamp by 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
    ts += 1000 

# Sending telemetry after building the complete list
try:
    route_point_tb_asset = API.find_asset(route.name)
    send_telemetry_asset(token, route_point_tb_asset.id.id, telemetry)
    print(f"Telemetry properly sent to {route.name}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error sending telemetry: {e}")

Key Changes Made

Timestamp Management: The timestamp is now correctly incremented with each iteration.

Position Indexing: The pos variable is incremented correctly to ensure it indexes into the longitude list properly.

Telemetry Construction: The telemetry data is built completely before being sent to avoid sending incomplete data.


With these adjustments, your code should now send all points of telemetry instead of just the last one. Make sure that both route_points_lat and route_points_lon lists are of equal length to avoid any index errors.
